# Is there a way to get the hash of a transaction from a contract?

Tags: solidity, transactions, hash

I've found that tx.hash is not defined in contracts, is there a way to get or calculate the hash of the tx ? And if not, What is the reason for that?

Is there a pattern to store information about a specific tx ?
Thanks

Comment: From the comments in the selected answer it should be possible, but it is not implemented. Perhaps someone can write a EIP for that.